# Copy whole files only

Tags: rsync, copy

Is there any way to copy directory from one filesystem to another but remove the partial file in case we run out of disk space on target filesystem?
I searched `cp` and `rsync` manuals but did not find anything; I could do this in a shell script but wanted to avoid it if possible.
At present I do:

```
cp -r /source /dest
```

or

```
rsync -avr /source /dest
```

m.

Comment: Does rsync really leave partial files?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the rsync manual, you can read:

```
--partial
     By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is
     interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially 
     transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file
     which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.
```

This means that you don't need to worry about partial transfer.

You can make sure of the `--partial-dir=DIR` option. Then, you can remove all files under this directory if you want to eliminate partially transferred files.

Comment: Actually, I looked at this switch already and even thought I'm not using it, the partial file is present on dest filesystem but with a different name (dot prefix and a few chars suffix).

Comment: I looked at this more closely and see this behavior, which seems strange to me: when using --partial-dir the partial file is not present on filesystem full even if --partial is specified as well; but this would achieve what I needed.

Comment: @mehturt: If so, you can accept this answer!

Comment: not really, because it does not say what is going on.  The answer I was looking for is to use --partial and --partial-dir and in that case the partial file is not present in partial-dir when running out of disk space, just like I described in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to check for free space before the copy is started (with a little space in excess).

The normal behaviour of cp is to drop the incomplete file.

Comment: This is not what I see (using cp on RHEL) - the incomplete file is present on dest filesystem.